# Soap Web Service- compare data entered against data from mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, web-services, soap, netbeans

I have a soap web service that is connected to mySQL database. It has two methods, one is insert() and the other is verify(). The first one enables the user to enter data such as name, email and password. It saves the records in the database successfully.

However am having problems with writing the verify method. It has as input parameters, email and password. It must compare the data entered with those stored in the database and return "registered" or "not registered" if it cant find the match in mysql database. Am having problem writing the codes. Could you please help, am new to jdbc and java web services. Am using netbeans. 
Thanks a lot.

Here are my codes:

```
    @WebMethod(operationName = "insert")
    public String insert(@WebParam(name = "name") String name,
    @WebParam(name = "email") String email,
    @WebParam(name = "password") String password {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con =          DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb", "root", "1234");
        PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement("insert into register values(?,?,?)");
        st.setString(1, name);
        st.setString(2, email);
        st.setString(3, password);
        st.executeUpdate();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return "record inserted";
}

/**
 * Web service operation
 */
@WebMethod(operationName = "Verify")
public String CheckUser(@WebParam(name = "email") String email,  
@WebParam(name = "password") String password) {

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con =  DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb", "root", "1234");

If
 // problems to write this statement!!! I need to compare the username and password 
// with some select * from register where password == @password and email == @email?

 return "Registered user";
 else 
    return "Not registered";

}
```

Comment: Do you know how to do the select? Or you have the select, but you don't know how to use it from java? (Also, I hope that you are not storing passwords in clear in the database).

Comment: I wont store it in clear i'll use sha1 or md5 to encrypt it.
I just want to get it to work first. No I'm confused, i dont know how to write it at all. :(

Please help me.

Comment: Could you pls share your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example could work (you might have to change column names in the query). Also, you should close the connection in the insert method, in the same way that this example.

```
    Connection con = null;

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb", "root", "1234");
        PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement("select 1 from register where password = ? and email = ? and name = ?");
        st.setString(1, password);
        st.setString(2, email);
        st.setString(3, name);

        ResultSet result = st.executeQuery();

        if (result.next()) { //.next() returns true if there is a next row returned by the query.
            return "Registered user";
        } else {
            return "Not registered";
        }


    } catch (Exception e) {
        //TODO manage the exception.
    } finally {
        if (con != null) {
            try {
                con.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {}
        }
    }
```

Comment: i just wanted to ask one more thing, say that in my database i have 3 columns: Name/email/Password and to verify() I only have as parameters: email and password. When I write:
    PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement("select 1 from register where password = ? and email = ? ");
        st.setString(1, password);
        st.setString(2, email);

It does not work! :(